# UITextField isn't white on iPhone simulator - Xcode 12.0.1

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield

When I create UITextField and place it on a View, it is displayed correctly (with white color) but when I run my app in simulator UITextField changes its color from default white to view's background color. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? See screenshots below.

Preview:

[image]

Simulator:

[image]

Comment: Try `yourTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white`

Comment: @aheze lol it works! But as far as I know it should be white as a default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in Xcode 12 you will need to set the text field's background color, as it now defaults to nil (clear). So as @aheze mentioned you'll need to set it to white manually with `yourTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white`.

Related to this question [UITextField backgroundColor set in Interface Builder is nil at runtime in iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62878121/uitextfield-backgroundcolor-set-in-interface-builder-is-nil-at-runtime-in-ios-14)